Why does Swift Compiler say, Non-sendable type 'X' returned by implicitly asynchronous call to nonisolated function cannot cross actor boundary?
I'm curious, can someone help me deal with a swift 6 error? Consider this code:
class Foo {
    init() async throws {}
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button ("Test") {
            Task {
                let _ = try await Foo()
            }
        }
    }
}

If the project's Swift Language Version is set to "Swift 6" (Xcode 16.0), then the let _ = ... line gives the following error:
Non-sendable type 'Foo' returned by implicitly asynchronous call to nonisolated function cannot cross actor boundary.
What is going on here? I already know how to make Foo Sendable - that's not what I'm looking for. Instead I'm trying to understand the situation regarding actors.
I believe that the Task closure will be run on the @MainActor. Somehow, the asynchronous initializer seems to be causing my Foo object to cross an actor boundary, but I don't see why. It probably has something to do with the implicit call referenced in the error. But what, exactly, is this implicit call? Could someone point me to some docs that explain this situation?
By the way, I know that making the Task detached solves this problem. But I still don't understand what's going on, exactly.

You said:

I believe that the Task closure will be run on the @MainActor.

Yes, the Task is isolated to the main actor. But Foo’s initializer is not.
Foo.init is an asynchronous initializer that is not isolated to any particular actor, so it will run on a “generic executor”. Add a MainActor.preconditionIsolated() in Foo’s initializer, and you will see it is not on the main actor:
class Foo {
    init() async {
        // if uncommented, the following results in runtime failure:
        //
        // MainActor.preconditionIsolated()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button ("Test") {
            Task {
                let _ = await Foo()
            }
        }
    }
}

That is the problem: Foo.init is non-isolated and is being returned to an isolated context; you cannot cross actor boundaries if Foo is not Sendable.

I think I understand. In my real situation, I don’t actually have control of the initializer code (it’s a 3rd party module), so I have no say in it being Sendable. How do I solve this situation?

A bunch of options: (1) Contact author and ask them how they would handle it and/or ETA for Swift 6 version of their code; (2) Stay in Swift 5 and use “Swift Concurrency Checking” of “Minimal” for now; (3) Don’t access object from isolated asynchronous contexts; (4) Find alternative library that achieves what you want but offers graceful Swift 6 support; or (5) If github repo, fork it and migrate it to Swift 6 yourself.

I must confess that it does not instill confidence in this third-party module that they made an async initializer (i.e., explicitly using Swift concurrency), but have not tackled Sendable concerns yet: We’ve had “Strict Concurrency Checking” of “Complete” for well over a year now, explicitly to give us a long runway to fix these issues…

I won't name the module/company, but it's a very big one and in widespread use (perhaps not the swift version, though). I will open some issues with them to address the problem, and use the other workarounds you suggested, in the meantime. Thanks for your insights!

I respect that, but if you don't get any answers on the framework’s support site, I would encourage you to go ahead and post a new question, but this time identifying the specific framework in question. We’re not trying to offend the framework authors, but it is important to connect you with folks who are using the framework in real-world scenarios. Not maybe that framework has its own forums (which is ideal because you connect with both committed users of the framework as well as its authors), so maybe that is even better. Good luck.
